# llamar un metodo en un activity Android

Tags: java, android

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month,int day){
        String date = day+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year;
  Activity1 act1 = new Activity1();
act1.MostrarDatos(date);
    }
```

como pueden ver quiero ejecutar un metodo del primer activity llamado `mostrar datos` pero no funciona se cierra mi app.

Metodo `MostrarDatos`

```
public void MostrarDatos(String Fecha) {
        try {
            Cursor cursor = basededatos.informacionPrincipal(Fecha); //////////////////////<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ATENCION
            if (cursor == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha presentado un problema al cargar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ninguna Corte", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
                return;
            }
            String[] columns = new String[]{
                    basededatos.COLUMN_ID,
                    basededatos.COLUMN_REGISTRO,
                    basededatos.COLUMN_HUERTO,
                    basededatos.COLUMN_UBICACION,
                    basededatos.COLUMN_ESTADO
            };

            int[] boundTo = new int[]{
                    R.id.txtCodigo_Listado,
                    R.id.txtCreacion_Listado,
                    R.id.txtHuerto_Listado,
                    R.id.txtUbicacion_Listado,
                    R.id.txtEstadoListado
            };

            customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.item_listado,cursor,columns,boundTo);
            listado.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha producido un error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Que error te muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: Es mejor que agregues los errores que te muestra el LogCat, por que si no, solamente estaremos adivinando y tardaremos mas en ayudarte a resolver tu problema

Comment: No es necesario el LogCat, **el problema es la referencia al ListView (listado) que al ser llamado el método desde otra Activity, la instancia tiene valor null.**

Comment: El error puede venir del CustomAdapter realmente no sabemos que tipo de contexto le este enviando. El error también puede venir del método informacionPrincipal no sabemos que pasa dentro.

Answer (score 4):

#### llamar un metodo en un activity Android.

Si tu método se tiene en tu Activity puedes definirlo como estatico y llamarlo desde otra aplicación de esta forma (Considerando la Activity donde se encuentra se llama MainActivity):

```
MainActivity.MostrarDatos(date);
```

Lo que veo pudiera cerrar tu aplicación es el contexto, así que podrías modificar tu método:

```
public static void MostrarDatos(Context context, String Fecha) {
    ... 
    ...
     Toast.makeText(context, "Se ha presentado un problema al cargar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ...
     Toast.makeText(context, "Ninguna Corte", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ...
    ...
```

y llamarias de esta forma el método:

```
MainActivity.MostrarDatos(getApplicationContext(), date);
```

---

El problema en tu caso es que haces referencia a un listado, el cual debería estar fuera del método en este caso, para que funcione correctamente:

```
        listado.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Comment: lo intento llamar así pero no funciona se me cierra la app.

Comment: @ManuelMorales  es por lo que te comentaba yo, estas utilizando elementos visuales de otra activity

Comment: Aquí el problema es que usas un ListView dentro del método que pertenece a la Activity,

Answer (score 3):

Esto **NO** va a funcionar. Ya que dentro de tu metodo haces un setAdapter de un elemento `listView` y manejas ids de elementos del layout de la Activity que intentas llamar.

Te recomiendo que crees una clase que se encargue de obtener los datos de tu base y retornarlos para asi manejarlos de distintas partes de tu proyecto (por ejemplo otras `Activitys`.

Por ejemplo, una clase que tenga métodos de inserción, selección, modificación y eliminación dependiendo tus necesidades.

Comment: ¿recomendación?

Comment: @ManuelMorales  edite amigo

Comment: Yo creo que puede funcionar, pero la implementación no es la correcta. Debes seguir los consejos de @sioesi

Comment: no se mucho de android como deberia quedar la clase? :/

Comment: @ManuelMorales es una clase java normal, en ella debes declarar una variable que hace referencia a tu base de datos y hacer todas tus consultas ahi mismo con el fin de retornar los valores que necesitas

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes llamar con la palabra reservada this

Ejemplo:

```
this.MostrarDatos(getApplicationContext(), date);
```

Si no estás en la misma clase sólo mandalo a llamar sin el this.

```
MostrarDatos(getApplicationContext(), date);
```